# How to count on join a table with 2 conditions?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, count, left-join

I have an `items` table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Nganu |
| 2 | Kae |
| 3 | Lho |

Also I have an `item_usages` table:

| id | item_id | user_id | usage_time |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 99 | 2021-10-07 00:00:00 |  |
| 2 | 2 | 99 | 2021-10-07 00:00:00 |  |
| 3 | 1 | 99 | 2021-10-08 00:00:00 |  |
| 4 | 1 | 22 | 2021-10-08 00:00:00 |  |
| 5 | 3 | 22 | 2021-10-08 00:00:00 |  |
| 6 | 1 | 99 | 2021-10-08 00:00:00 |  |

I want to find an item's total usage and user usage in a query. an example I would like to find user_id 99 usage, expected result:

| id | name | total_usage | user_usage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Kae | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | Nganu | 4 | 3 |
| 3 | Lho | 1 | 0 |

I tried:

```
select 
    "items".*,
    count(total_usage.id) as total_usage, 
    count(user_usage.id) as user_usage 
from 
    "items"
left join 
    "item_usages" as "total_usage" on "items"."id" = "total_usage"."item_id"
left join 
    "item_usages" as "user_usage" on "user_usage"."item_id" = "items"."id" 
                                  and "user_usage"."user_id" = 99
group by 
    "items"."id";
```

but it returns:

| id | name | total_usage | user_usage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Kae | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | Nganu | 12 | 12 |
| 3 | Lho | 1 | 0 |

`item_usages` only have 6 rows, why Nganu have 12 on both usage? How to fix my query?

I tried on PostgreSQL 12.8 and 13.4, I also tested on SQLFiddle(PostgreSQL 9.6), Here is the link:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f1aac/5

I got the query that returned the correct result:

```
select 
    "items".*,
    min(total_usage.total_count) as total_usage, 
    count(user_usage.id) as user_usage 
from "items"
left join 
    (select item_id,count(item_id) as total_count  from item_usages group by item_id) as total_usage 
     on "items"."id" = "total_usage"."item_id"
left join "item_usages" as "user_usage" 
     on "user_usage"."item_id" = "items"."id" and "user_usage"."user_id" = 99
 group by "items"."id";
```

But I don't know about the performance, so  I still find faster query if possible and still wondering:

**Why does my first query give wrong result?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your query returns high numbers is that you join 2 times.

(From the side of Nganu) The first join will result in 4 rows, the second will map those 4 rows with 3 rows of the same table, resulting in 12 rows.

You can solve this problem with only 1 join:

```
select "items".id, 
count(total_usage.id) as total_usage, 
sum(case when total_usage.user_id = 99 then 1 else 0 end) as user_usage
from "items"
left join "item_usages" as "total_usage" on "items"."id" = "total_usage"."item_id"
group by "items".id
```

And it should work faster (though, on a small dataset is not visible)

Comment: Thanks, but how to combine with having query, i tried `having sum(case when total_usage.user_id = 99 then 1 else 0 end) < 2` but doesnt work

Comment: I had a typo on my last test, it worked using having, and faster than my query based on my test. Thanks you very much.

Comment: I would suggest wrapping the result of my query in a second one and there just filter i.e "WHERE user_usage < 2"

Comment: Will it be significantly faster than `having`? If not I will still prefer using having, because I am using ORM, it's difficult to wrap the result like you mentioned in ORM.

Comment: Not at all, just easier to read, in my opinion